# Protractor test hangs when clicking on element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have been trying to write a protractor test that selects an item from a custom dropdown menu. The only problem is that when it tries to click an element other than the last one in the list it hangs and timesout. When I remove the click() method invocation it seems to work fine. Since all these calls are done asynchronously I also don't see a way of stopping the loop when it finds the element. My code looks like this:

```
    var it = null;
    for(var i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfAccounts; i++) {
        var listItemLocator = '//div[@id="payment-accounts"]/div/ul/li[' + i + ']/label/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]';
        var item = browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.xpath(listItemLocator));
        item.getText().then(function(value) {
            if(value === accountNumber) {
                it = item;
            }
           console.log(value);
        })
        .then(function clickOption() {
            console.log('Clicking...');
            if (it) {
                console.log('Clicking desired item');
                it.click();
                console.log('Clicked..');
            }
        })
    }
```

I also tried this approach:

```
this.selectRichSelectOption = function (selector, item) {

    var selectList = browser.driver.findElement(selector);
    selectList.click();

    var desiredOption = '';
    var i = 1;
    selectList.findElements(protractor.By.tagName('li'))
        .then(function findMatchingOption(options) {

            console.log(options);

            options.some(function (option) {

                console.log('Option:');
                console.log(option);
                var listItemLocator = '//div[@id="payment-accounts"]/div/ul/li[' + i + ']/label/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]';
                console.log(listItemLocator);
                var element = option.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('//label/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]'));
                console.log('Element:');
                console.log(element);
                i++;

                element.getText().then(function (value) {
                    console.log('Value: ' + value);
                    console.log('Item:');
                    console.log(item);
                    if (item === value) {
                        console.log('Found option..');
                        desiredOption = option;
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        })
        .then(function clickOption() {
            console.log('Click option');
            console.log(desiredOption);
            if (desiredOption) {
                console.log('About to click..');
                desiredOption.click();
            }
        });
};
```

The result of this one is even more strange. Now all of a sudden the getText() method invocation returns an empty String. But when I try to retrieve the e.g. the class attribute I get the correct value back. Where did the Text value go?

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem, on which browsers did you test? I met an [issue on Firefox with options](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/480) and there are others with dropdowns in general.

Comment: I ran the test on Chrome. A normal drop down works fine. We are using a custom drop down which is build up from multiple divs and ul tags. In general this is not really a big issue since you can reach the elements by using xpath. Using the normal Selenium API (not webdriver) I actually can achieve what I want by looping through the elements by using xpath. With Selenium Webdriver API this seems to be a bit more complex. Since they use asynchronous calls chaining to  be able to loop through elements.

Comment: The problem I am currently having is that whenever I go through the options and try to get the text value by calling getText() it seems to be empty. So my comparison fails to find the element I want to select from the drop down.

Comment: When I use the loop approach (first one) it seems to work only when I try to select the last item in the drop down. Whenever I try to select any other item than the last item it basically hangs and the test timesout for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with page load. After you select, the page does not load completely.

Try using a browser.sleep(timeInMs);

Answer (score 0):

try using node 8+'s async functions such as `await`. I went through this headache and it was solved by `await`ing for certain things to appear or have certain attributes.

`await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath('path leading to element based off attribute'))))`

Good luck